# Error with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know what am I missing in the code?

```
set.seed(12345)
require(ggplot2)
AData <- data.frame(Glabel=LETTERS[1:7], A=rnorm(7, mean = 0, sd = 1), B=rnorm(7, mean = 0, sd = 1))
TData <- data.frame(Tlabel=LETTERS[11:20], A=rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1), B=rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1))
i <- 2
j <- 3
p <- ggplot(data=AData, aes(AData[, i], AData[, j])) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(data=AData, label=Glabel), size=3, vjust=1.25, colour="black")
p <- p + geom_segment(data = TData, aes(xend = TData[ ,i], yend=TData[ ,j]),
                  x=0, y=0, colour="black",
                  arrow=arrow(angle=25, length=unit(0.25, "cm")))
p <- p + geom_text(data=TData, aes(label=Tlabel), size=3, vjust=1.35, colour="black")
```

Last line of the code produces the error. Please point me out how to figure out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` and `j` are not defined in the code chunk. Also, you would normally refer to the column name in `aes()` **not** subset the data object. SO what are `i` and `j` and what are you really trying to do? As it stands, you are asking for code review without saying what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but the line that fails is the last line, because you haven't mapped new x and y variables in the mapping. `geom_text()` needs x and y coords but you only provide the `label` argument, so **ggplot** takes x and y from `p`, which has only 7 rows of data whilst `Tlabel` is of length 10. That explains the error. I presume you mean to plot at x = A and y = B of `TData`? If so, this works:

```
p + geom_text(data=TData, mapping = aes(A, B, label=Tlabel), 
              size=3, vjust=1.35, colour="black")
```

Answer (score 2):

(This might get a better answer on the `ggplot` mailing list.)

It looks like you're trying to display some kind of biplot ... the root of your problem is that you're violating the idiom of ggplot, which wants you to specify variables in a way that's consistent with the scope of the data.

Maybe this does what you want, via some `aes_string` trickery that substitutes the names of the desired columns ...

```
varnames <- colnames(AData)[-1]
v1 <- varnames[1]
v2 <- varnames[2]
p <- ggplot(data=AData,
            aes_string(x=v1, y=v2)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
## took out redundant 'data', made size bigger so I could see the labels
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label=Glabel), size=7, vjust=1.25, colour="black")
p <- p + geom_segment(data = TData, aes_string(xend = v1, yend=v2),
                  x=0, y=0, colour="black",
                  arrow=arrow(angle=25, length=unit(0.25, "cm")))
## added colour so I could distinguish this second set of labels
p <- p + geom_text(data=TData,
                   aes(label=Tlabel), size=10, vjust=1.35, colour="blue")
```

Comment: PS it would be nice to displace the second set of labels in the same direction as the arrows so they were always "in front" of the arrows, but I don't know a really quick way to do that.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to display a biplot. Thanks for nice answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: Cool idea about the direction of labels for arrows.

Comment: @Ben Bolker. There you go, giving the kids crazy ideas: See what you caused? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451116/arrows-label-direction-in-ggplot2